# How to set the XML attribute 'layout_constrainedWidth' of ConstraintLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In Constraint Layout, how to convert the xml attribute:

`app:layout_constrainedWidth=”true|false”`

in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this out.

So base on the answers above,

`constrainedWidth` can be accessed through `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` and thus can be altered by the following code: (Thank you @JeelVankhede)

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
myView.getLayoutParams(); // View for which we need to set constrainedWidth.
lp.constrainedWidth = true/false;
myView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

However when using `ConstraintsSet` the following code would be needed:

```
val constraintLayout = // your constraint layout
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)

// This is the imporatant part
constraint.constrainDefaultWidth(R.id.yourViewId, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_WRAP)

constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me bananas, but constrainDefaultWidth did the trick for a progammatically created and constrained views.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set `constrainedWidth/Height` programatically, then you've to take `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` for your view and set the flag named **constrainedWidth** or **constrainedHeight** at your will.

I.e.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams(); // View for which we need to set constrainedWidth.
lp.constrainedWidth = true/false;
myView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

---

**constrainedWidth**

> Specify if the horizontal dimension is constrained in case both left &
>   right constraints are set and the widget dimension is not a fixed
>   dimension.
>
> By default, if a widget is set to `WRAP_CONTENT`, we will
>   treat that dimension as a **fixed dimension**, meaning the dimension will
>   not change regardless of constraints.
>
> Setting this attribute to **true**
>   allows the dimension to change in order to respect constraints.

Check out [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html#constrainedwidth).