# Android - ConstraintLayout set Percent Height programmatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-constraintlayout

here is my layout :

```
...
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
>
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/myclayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                ></android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
...
```

how to set constraintHeight_percent programmatically ?

I tried with ConstraintSet but did not work

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.constrainPercentHeight(R.id.myclayout, (float) 0.4);
set.applyTo(((ConstraintLayout) vw.findViewById(R.id.myclayout)));
```

Comment: Check my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230893/10271334, you can get reference from it.

Comment: For what it's worth, a major benefit of the `ConstraintLayout` is to avoid nesting; seeing them nested within one another is a red flag. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the right answer is :

> ```
>     ConstraintLayout mConstrainLayout  = (ConstraintLayout) vw.findViewById(R.id.myclayout);
>     ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mConstrainLayout.getLayoutParams();
>     lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = (float) 0.4;
>     mConstrainLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I went with using a *ConstraintSet* to update the width and height of a *ConstraintLayout's* child:

```
        val set = ConstraintSet()
        set.clone(parentLayout) // parentLayout is a ConstraintLayout
        set.constrainPercentWidth(childElement.id, .5f)
        set.constrainPercentHeight(childElement.id, .5f)
        set.applyTo(parentLayout)
```

...the float values should be a percentage mapped to the unit interval.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and thankfully found this post. I developed a virtual musical instrument app, a steel drum/pan app with eight different UIs having circular shaped main elements. I used one layout for all screen size for each of the eight UIs to reduce layout redundancy and wanted to keep the aspect ratio of the circular elements on most devices with different screen resolutions. So I had to use layout_constraintWidth_percent and layout_constraintHeight_percent to resize the parent layout according to device screen aspect ratio. I used @beginner's code above and combined with code for calculating screen aspect ratio and consequent implementation of the idea. Here is the code:

```
// instantiate constraint layout inside OnCreate
ConstraintLayout mcLayout =findViewById(R.id.layout_myConstraintLayout);
    
//determine display aspect ratio
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
assert wm != null;
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
assert display != null;
display.getMetrics(metrics);
float width = metrics.widthPixels;
float height = metrics.heightPixels;
float ratio = width/height;
float aspectRatio = round(ratio, 2);
Log.d("DISPLAYRATIO", "Display Ration is: " + displayRatio);

// create contraintlayout set for mConstraintLayout and params
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
lowTenorBkg.getLayoutParams();

// set percent width and height acacording to screen display aspect ratio
if (aspectRatio > 1.30f && aspectRatio < 1.42f) {
    // Add constraints
    lp.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.96f;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 0.78f;
} else if (aspectRatio > 1.40f && aspectRatio < 1.60f) {
    // Add constraints
    lp.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.96f;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 0.83f;
} else if (aspectRatio > 1.58f && aspectRatio < 1.67f) {
    // Add constraints
    lp.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.96f;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 0.93f;
} else if (aspectRatio > 1.65f && aspectRatio <= 1.71f) {
    // Add constraints
    lp.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.92f;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 0.94f;
} else if (aspectRatio > 1.72f && aspectRatio <= 1.78f) {
    // Add constraints
    lp.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.875f;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 0.94f;
} else if (aspectRatio > 1.78f && aspectRatio <= 2.05f) {
    // Add constraints
    lp.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.8f;
    lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 0.93f;
}

lowTenorBkg.setLayoutParams(lp);
set.applyTo(mcLayout);

// put the round method inside the activity class 
// method for rounding float number to decimal places
public static float round(float d, int decimalPlace) {
   return BigDecimal.valueOf(d).setScale(decimalPlace,
   BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).floatValue();
}
```